# PyQt Call Function Does Not Work

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

So I am using QT to create a GUI in Python.

I have created the *.ui code and converted it to *.py
The next step is to create a line of code in python to call the newley converted *.py code.

This is the converted .ui code now in .py:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(383, 54)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 61, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 10, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.lineEdit.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Enter Text"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Clear"))
```

Now I am creating a call function, this is the part that does not seem to work. I have written the code and can not see any error at all. If anyone could help it would be truly appreciated:

```
    import sys
from FirstApp import *

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def _init_(self,parent=none):
        QtGui.QWidget._init_(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if _name_ == "_main_":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

p.s
This is all for my online degree, unfortunately we have no tutors and have to seek online help when we get stuck. This is why I am creating this GUI this way.

Answer (score 1):

The second part is quite buggy, try this one :

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from FirstApp import *
import sys

class MyForm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

(be careful about double underscores everywhere, or `None` not `none`)

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! It is bizarre because the prescribed book I am using suggests the code I have submitted above. So far it is a rather disappointing publication. Hence I am on this site. Thank you again!

Comment: `QtGui.QApplication` might work with Pyqt4, maybe the book targets the older version of Pyqt

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this is an older question, but I happened to stumble across it and am aware of an easier way. In my case, I was able to convert the *.ui file into an *.py file using pyside2. By navigating to the folder the the *.ui file is in and then running this on the command line

```
pyside2-uic <name_of_ui_file> <name_of_*.ui_file>.py
```

an *.py file will be generated in that folder as well.

For example, if my *.ui file was called 'form.ui' and placed on my desktop. I would CD into my desktop and then run

```
pyside2-uic form.ui > form.py
```

and form.py would be generated inside of my folder.